# cocos2d-x use lua, how to inheritance a c++ class and overwirite it's funcitons

Tags: c++, lua, cocos2d-x

I want to define a lua table, inheritance c++ class `cc.Node`, and overwirite the `getContentSize()` function, return a new contentsize.

```
-- here, how to inheritance cc.Node
local Ball = class('Ball')

function Ball:ctor()
end

function Ball:getContentSize()
     local width -- here, how to call super getContentSize
     local height
     return cc.size(width + 10, height + 10)
end

return Ball
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lua table is a interesting type, you can do like this.

```
local Ball = class('Ball', function() return cc.Node:create() end)
```

but inheritance c++ class is not support `super` operate. you can call super funciton like this.

```
local _getContentSize = cc.Node.getContentSize

function Ball:getContentSize()
    local width = _getContentSize(self).width
    local height = _getContentSize(self).height
    return cc.size(width + 10, height + 10)
end
```

even you can extend cc.Node without inheritance.

```
local Ball = cc.Node
function Ball:newfunc()
end
```

you can call `newfunc` in all cc.Node object in lua.